# Cannot find `.exe` files (in PATH) from CMD after installing WSL

Tags: windows-10, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 using WSL, I cannot run `.exe` files from CMD without providing the suffix `.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `PATHEXT` in CMD does not include the `PATHEXT` set from the System environment variables any more:

[image]

If I type from CMD:

```
> echo %PATHEXT%
.PL
```

Notice that the settings from the system variables are not included. You can fix this by adding `.exe` to PATHEXT for the *User variables* (not system variables):

[image]

If I now close CMD and reopen:

```
> echo %PATHEXT%
.ext;.bat;.PL
```